# limiting number of clients on IP C++

Tags: c++, ip, tcpclient

I want to limit access to the device for more than 4 clients on IP address.

```
struct sockaddr_in peerAddr;
SOCK_LEN_TYPE peerAddrLen = sizeof(peerAddr);
// Yes, socket is free, try to accept a connection on it
connectionSocketArr[sockIdx] = accept(listenSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &peerAddr,
                                     &peerAddrLen);
```

Comment: So `sockIdx` should be in the range zero to three, inclusive? (And this question is a hint for you.)

Comment: sockIdx will not limit number of client but it will set file descriptor for select call

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sockIdx` variable to see how many clients are currently connected.

Instead of storing the socket returned by `accept` directly in the array, store it in a temporary variable. If `sockIdx` is larger than `3` then the new client is not allowed to connect, so send a message to the client stating that and close the socket. Otherwise store the socket in the array and increase `sockIdx`.